# Home work about Matrix containing another matrix ( Check if true or false)

Tags: java, matrix

So the instructions are to create a matrix 10x10 and randomize values between 1~20 for each index
Then ask the user to enter 6 numbers between 1~20, and use those numbers to create
another 2x3 Matrix.
Then the program has to check if the 10x10 matrix contains the 2x3 matrix from the user.
Also i'm not allowed to use functions.

Example for input:

Enter the1 number in the matrix: 17
Enter the2 number in the matrix: 17
Enter the3 number in the matrix: 17
Enter the4 number in the matrix: 5
Enter the5 number in the matrix: 13
Enter the6 number in the matrix: 14

Output:

The random matrix:

14 14 3 18 2 10 19 10 3 3

2 17 15 16 5 17 7 17 15 10

13 1 3 9 5 4 11 9 1 8

17 14 13 9 8 1 18 3 17 18

12 17 5 14 13 4 16 14 13 4

8 12 8 19 6 5 3 3 14 18

16 16 17 9 9 10 17 3 8 5

13 8 6 17 6 17 17 7 19 5

5 14 6 15 11 11 13 17 17 17

17 13 13 18 11 4 15 5 13 14

The matrix you entered:

17 17 17

5 13 14

The random matrix contains the users matrix.

My Code so far =

```
            int[][] big = new int[10][10];
            int[][] small =new int [][] {{the1,the2,the3},{the4,the5,the6}};

            for(int i = 0; i < big.length; i++ )
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < big[i].length; j++)
                {
                    big[i][j]= (int)((Math.random()*20)+1);

                }

            }
            for(int i =0; i < big.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < big.length; j++)
                {
                    Boolean isEqual=true;
                    for(int k = 0; k < 2 && isEqual; k++)
                    {
                        for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                        {
                            if (big[i+k][j+m]!=small[k][m])
                            {
                                isEqual=false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

My general idea was basically running through the indexes of the big matrix while checking for equal numbers, and if one found, the routine continues, otherwise it breaks, and going to the next index in the big matrix.

Comment: Your outer two loops will likely encounter IndexOutOfBounds exceptions whenever i or j is greater than 7. Can you see why?

Comment: @FredK i dont get indexOutOfBounds  while running this program, although im not sure if its working because i never got a match so far

Comment: That's because you probably execute the break statement before encountering the error. You reference `big[i+k][j+m]` but what happens if i is `big.length-1` and k is 1? Then you reference `big[big.length]`, which is beyond the bounds of big.

Answer (score 0):

Your general idea is correct and should work for the described scenario. The only issue you are having is your break statement doesent work as you think.

According to nested loop, if you put break statement in inner loop, compiler will jump out from inner loop and continue the outer loop again. If you need to jump out from the outer loop using break statement given inside inner loop you can use a labelled loop, i.e give your loop a name and use it with the break statement.

In your code above you shold not only breake the inner most loop but also the one above:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] big = new int[10][10];
        int[][] small = new int[][]{{12, 13, 14}, {13, 14, 15}};
        for (int i = 0; i < big.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < big[i].length; j++) {
                big[i][j]= (int)((Math.random()*20)+1);
            }
        }
        // just added this loop to print the random array so you can check the output
        for(int[] row : big){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<big.length-1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<big[0].length-2; j++){
                boolean isEqual = true;
  LoopIwannaBreak:for(int k = 0; k<small.length; k++){
                    for(int m = 0; m<small[0].length; m++){
                        if(big[i+k][j+m] != small[k][m]){
                            isEqual = false;
                            break LoopIwannaBreak;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // added this to tell at which index the match was found
               if(isEqual){
                   System.out.println("found at big["+i+"]["+j+"]");
               }
            }
        }
    }
```